# Why does the algorithm return ['NoneType' is not iterable] Error

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

```py
def arrayNesting(nums):
    new_nums = []
    seen = []
    k = 0
    for num in nums:
        new_nums = new_nums.append(nums[k])
        seen = seen.append(nums[k])
        k = nums[k]
        if k in seen:
            break
        else:
            continue
    return len(new_nums)

arrayNesting([0,1,2])
```

The code returns an error:

> 'NoneType' is not iterable

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Please send your code as text instead of image

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, at the line `new_nums = new_nums.append(nums[k])`

You do not need to assign it to anything, so it will be

```py
new_nums.append(nums[k])
```

Also, you are not printing the result, you only call the function.

```py
def arrayNesting(nums):
    new_nums = []
    seen = []
    k = 0
    for num in nums:
        new_nums.append(nums[k])
        seen = seen.append(nums[k])
        k = nums[k]
        if k in seen:
            break
        else:
            continue
    return len(new_nums)

a = arrayNesting([0,1,2])
print(a)
```

Comment: Same logic should be applied to the `seen = seen.append()` line right?

Comment: Yes, correct. Didn't see the `seen = seen.append` line